# Printing all possibilities of leaf elements of 3-D array in PHP

Tags: php

I have an issue and trying to solve in php. I need ideas of yours for solving this issue. 
I'm gonna try to explain, hope I can.

I have an array like this:

```
$mainArr = array(array("a","b","c"),array("1","2","3"),array("x","y","z"));
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            [2] => c
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => x
            [1] => y
            [2] => z
        )

)
```

What I'm trying to do is printing all 3 possibilities of leaf elements. Like that:

```
a1x
a1y
a1z

a2x
a2y
a2z

a3x
a3y
a3z

b1x
b1y
b1z

.
.
.
```

I try to form an algorithm to make this, but I got stuck.

Can you please help me for this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You should check [RecursiveIteratorIterator](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) 
I believe this is solution for your problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($mainArr[0] as $level1)
  foreach ($mainArr[1] as $level2)
    foreach ($mainArr[2] as $level3)
      echo $level1 . $level2 . $level3 . "<br />";
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

This solution is valid if we know the number of leaf-top nodes. In our case, its 3.

But what if we don't know the number of nodes.

For example, if $mainArr has 3 elements, solution is true but what if we dont know how much element $mainArr has?

Comment: Then you'd use a one-line recursive function. If you had asked that question, I would have provided the answer to it.